# Adding a new column to dataframe based on values of another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two python dataframes df1 and df2.
 `df2` has columns A, B, C.
 `df1` has columns A, B, D where the pair of values in A and B may repeat.

I want to add a new column C such that it takes values from df2.
For example:
`df2` has the following entries: [ (1,2,0), (2,1,3), (3,4,10)]
 and
 `df1` has entries [(1,2,2), (1,2,5), (3,4,5), (1,2,7), (3,4,3)]
The final result I want is [(1,2,2,0), (1,2,5,0), (3,4,5,10), (1,2,7,0), (3,4,3,10)].
I wrote the following code in python

```
result = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['A','B'])
result.head()
```

But the result is an empty dataframe.

Comment: so you want a new column that has tuple of all the unique values???

Comment: Please *show* your desired output and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because you're using tuples when creating the original dataframes. This will result in one column holding the tuples instead of columns A, B, C and D. Here's code that works:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [[1,2,2], [1,2,5], [3,4,5], [1,2,7], [3,4,3]]
data2 = [[1,2,0], [2,1,3], [3,4,10]] 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['A', 'B', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'])
#df['tuple'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['A'], row['B'], row['C'], row['D']), axis=1)
df['tuple'] = list(zip(df.A, df.B, df.C, df.D))

df
```

Output is:

```
    A   B   D   C   tuple
0   1   2   2   0   (1, 2, 0, 2)
1   1   2   5   0   (1, 2, 0, 5)
2   1   2   7   0   (1, 2, 0, 7)
3   3   4   5   10  (3, 4, 10, 5)
4   3   4   3   10  (3, 4, 10, 3)
```